# Most general hypotheses to have matrix-exponential as solution of linear matrix-ODE?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices

What are the most general hypotheses under which the exponential function $\exp(-B(t))$, with $B(t)$ the indefinite integral of a real Lebesgue-integrable $d\times d$-matrix function $A(t)$, solves the matrix ODE $X'(t)+A(t).X(t)=0$?

Clearly assuming that $A(t)$ commutes with $B(t)$ for all $t$ suffices, 
but how does one guarantee this?

Does it suffice to assume that:

- $A(t)$ commutes with $A(s)$ for all $t, s$

or

- $A(t)$ is symmetric, for all $t$?

Comment: Assuming $[B(t),B'(t)]=0$ and letting $X(t)=e^{-B(t)}$ turns the ODE into $(-B'(t)+A(t))X(t)=0$. This follows from your first assumption, so it is sufficient. If $A$s at different times don't commute, the solution is given by the so-called time ordered exponential (instead of the usual exponential) of the integral of $A$.

Comment: Merely assuming that $A(t)$ is symmetric for all $t$ will not work, as easy examples show.  Your first assumption is sufficient, as it is equivalent to assuming that the values $A(t)$ all lie in an abelian subalgebra of the Lie algebra ${\frak{gl}}_d$ of $d$-by-$d$ matrices.  More generally, as Lie showed, one can solve $X'(t) + A(t) X(t) = 0$ by a *sequence* of exponentiations and integrations (i.e., quadrature) whenever the values $A(t)$ all lie in a *solvable* Lie subalgebra $\frak{s}\subset{\frak{gl}}_d$.